# hide various divs -jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is possible join this code, in something less redundant?

```
$('#x').hide();
$('#y').hide();
$('#z').hide();
```

i already tried   `$('#x', '#y', '#z').hide();` but didn't work.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#x, #y, #z').hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried:

```
$('#x, #y, #z').hide();
```